# Oracle: Using local index as primary key for partitioned table?

Tags: oracle, indexing, partitioning

Is it possible to use a local index as a primary key in Oracle, if the table is partitioned?

For example, if the table had columns of `A, B, C, D, E`, partitioned by `A` and `B`, and the desired primary key was on columns `A, B, C, D`, then can a local index on `C, D` be used as a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local unique index must be prefixed - i.e., the leading columns of the index must be the partitioning key(s).  So a unique index would have to be on `(A, B, C, D)`.

Comment: One thing that may help - especially if using list partitioning - is to enable columnar compression on that index to fit more entries on a block, making the overall index smaller.

Answer (score 0):

create table Tab1 (A number, B number)
partition by list (A)
(partition p1
values (1),
partition p2
values (2),
partition pmax
values (default))
/
Table created.

SQL>  alter table Tab1 add constraint t1_pk primary key(A,B) using index local
/
Table altered.